# Vagrant's use against Hyper-V

Tags: automation, vagrant, hyper-v

I am getting my feet wet with `Vagrant`.

I am trying to use it to auto deploy a number of Windows Server 2012 VMs automatically. I am running into some bugs in that Hyper-V does not seem to be a first class citizen in terms of attention and support from Vagrant in relation to other operating systems and virtualization platforms.

When researching Hyper-V, I find it also supports automated deployment.

So my question is, **what is the main benefit to using Vagrant on top of Hyper-V alone? I am not countering its usefulness, I am more asking what can be gained from it that Hyper-V alone could not handle as well?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of using Vagrant is that you could easily support other host OSes than Windows. If you use Hyper-V alone you're stuck to Windows as a host. But if you ever need to run your Windows Server 2012 VMs on Linux, you could do that easily by adding support for different providers than Hyper-V, e.g. for VirtualBox, to your Vagrant box, and then just `vagrant up` it under Linux.